# How to repeat an object multiple times in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an object

```
SpecialObj={
0:[{lqd: 88, date: "2017-08-18 09:30:00"},
   {lqd: 77, date: "2017-08-19 14:00:00"}
],
1:[
    {lqd: 33, date: "2017-08-17 10:30:00"},
    {lqd: 11, date: "2017-08-16 12:00:00"}
],
2:[
    {lqd: 44, date: "2017-08-14 13:30:00"},
    {lqd: 55, date: "2017-08-15 15:00:00"}
]
```

}

I want to repeat the array inside of that object 3 times. The output should be as below...

```
    SpecialObj={
0:[{lqd: 88, date: "2017-08-18 09:30:00"},
   {lqd: 77, date: "2017-08-19 14:00:00"}
],
1:[
    {lqd: 33, date: "2017-08-17 10:30:00"},
    {lqd: 11, date: "2017-08-16 12:00:00"}
],
2:[
    {lqd: 44, date: "2017-08-14 13:30:00"},
    {lqd: 55, date: "2017-08-15 15:00:00"}
],
3:[{lqd: 88, date: "2017-08-18 09:30:00"},
   {lqd: 77, date: "2017-08-19 14:00:00"}
],
4:[
    {lqd: 33, date: "2017-08-17 10:30:00"},
    {lqd: 11, date: "2017-08-16 12:00:00"}
],
5:[
    {lqd: 44, date: "2017-08-14 13:30:00"},
    {lqd: 55, date: "2017-08-15 15:00:00"}
],
6:[{lqd: 88, date: "2017-08-18 09:30:00"},
   {lqd: 77, date: "2017-08-19 14:00:00"}
],
7:[
    {lqd: 33, date: "2017-08-17 10:30:00"},
    {lqd: 11, date: "2017-08-16 12:00:00"}
],
8:[
    {lqd: 44, date: "2017-08-14 13:30:00"},
    {lqd: 55, date: "2017-08-15 15:00:00"}
]
```

}

I was trying with below way but result coming different object 3 times, but I need single object like above

```
function fillArray(value) {
  var arr1 = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    arr1.push(value);
  }
  return arr1;
}
```

Can I have the simplest way to do this with javascript?

Comment: The above is not an array..

Comment: the above is not an object.

Comment: 0, 1, 2, etc are properties of the object. There is no array anywhere in your example data. I suggest you read up on the difference between arrays and objects in javascript

Comment: It's neither an array nor a valid object.  Please test your code for obvious syntax errors and typos before posting a question!

Comment: The update to the question is also invalid syntax.  The inner arrays are now fine, but the containing object needs keys for each array (or else it needs to be an array instead of an object.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the object pattern is adjusted to an array of objects for value of property you can use `Object.keys()` to get current `.length` of properties, `for` loop to set additional properties to `Object.keys(object).length * 3`

```js
const o = {
    0:[{lqd: 1000, date: "2017-08-18 09:30:00"},
       {lqd: 6500, date: "2017-08-18 14:00:00"}
    ],
    1:[
        {lqd: 1000, date: "2017-08-18 09:30:00"},
        {lqd: 6500, date: "2017-08-18 14:00:00"}
    ],
    2:[
        {lqd: 1000, date: "2017-08-18 09:30:00"},
        {lqd: 6500, date: "2017-08-18 14:00:00"}
    ]
};

for (let len = Object.keys(o).length, i = len; i < len * 3; i++) {
  Object.assign(o, {[i]: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(o[i -1]))});
}

console.log(o);
```

Comment: Hi @guest271314, In your code after 2nd index its only repeating 2nd index data 6 times. which is not expected. please change the object set for different value then you can understand.

Comment: @Ajay Substitute `o[i % 3]` for `o[i - 1]` at `Object.assign(o, {[i]: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(o[i - 1]))`

Comment: Thanks @guest271314, Its working fine now after change.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, your object doesn't make too much sense and there isn't an array anywhere in it.

I took a crack at assuming what your obj should probably look like.

`specialObj` is an object with numbered keys that can hold multiple objects(an array). Each object in the array has properties `lqd` and `date`.
`

```js
var specialObj = {};

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  specialObj[i] = [];
  for (var x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
    var newObj = {};
    newObj.liquidity = 5500
    newObj.date = new Date();
    specialObj[i].push(newObj);
  }
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(specialObj, null, 2));
```

Comment: Hi @Andrew your solution is creating extra array which was not as per my expectation if you refer my expected output now and your output you can understand the difference.

Comment: Your object is still not correct syntax, I did update my answer though with what you may need.

Comment: Hi @ Andrew I can not use your code as you have taken it like below... newObj.lqd = 6500;
  newObj.date = new Date(); separately. Please use var newObj = {
    0:[{liquidity: 5500, date: "2017-08-18 10:00:00"},{liquidity: 57, date: "2017-08-18 10:30:00"}],
    1:[{liquidity: 5500, date: "2017-08-18 10:00:00"},{liquidity: 57, date: "2017-08-18 10:30:00"}],
    2:[{liquidity: 5500, date: "2017-08-18 10:00:00"},{liquidity: 57, date: "2017-08-18 10:30:00"}]
  }; as reference object if possible.

Comment: Hi @Andrew, I have updated my object can you please check now, actually you are considering single set of data I have multiple and it should duplicate 3 times same set of data with same sequence. please refer the input and output set. and thank you